# Setting up html report with Jasmine

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm new to BDD and Jasmine, and I'm not able to configure https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-pretty-html-reporter to get html of test pass rate.

There it mentions a basic setup:

```
var Jasmine = require('jasmine');
var HtmlReporter = require('jasmine-pretty-html-reporter').Reporter;
var jasmine = new Jasmine();

jasmine.loadConfigFile('./spec/support/jasmine.json');

// options object
jasmine.addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
  path: path.join(__dirname,'results')
}));

jasmine.execute();
```

However, I'm not sure where should I perform those configuration (in which file).
Could anyone help me with this, please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The setup provided by this package is used `jasmine` as a library. See [Using the library](https://jasmine.github.io/setup/nodejs.html#using-the-library).

This means we can execute test cases programmatically. We execute this module via `node`, e.g.

Folder structure:

```sh
⚡  tree -L 2 -I 'node_modules'
.
├── README.md
├── jasmine.json
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── helpers
│   └── stackoverflow
├── test-reporter
│   └── report.html
└── tsconfig.json

4 directories, 6 files
```

`src/stackoverflow/70338811/as-a-library.js`:

```js
var Jasmine = require('jasmine');
var path = require('path');
var HtmlReporter = require('jasmine-pretty-html-reporter').Reporter;
var jasmine = new Jasmine();

jasmine.loadConfigFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../jasmine.json'));

jasmine.addReporter(
  new HtmlReporter({
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../../../test-reporter'),
  }),
);

jasmine.execute();
```

```sh
npx ts-node <Absolute_path>/src/stackoverflow/70338811/as-a-library.js
```

If you want to use `jasmine` as a CLI and run the test cases via `npm script`. You should add this custom reporter to the Jasmine environment. See [Reporters](https://jasmine.github.io/setup/nodejs.html#reporters). We need to create a helper file in `src/helpers` folder to add custom reporter, e.g. `pretty-html-reporter.js`

```js
var HtmlReporter = require('jasmine-pretty-html-reporter').Reporter;
var path = require('path');

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
  new HtmlReporter({
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../../test-reporter'),
  }),
);
```

`npm script`:

```json
"test": "ts-node node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine --config=./jasmine.json",
```

Now, let's run test cases of a specific file.

```sh
 ⚡  npm t /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples/src/stackoverflow/69830430/index.test.ts
> jasmine-examples@ test /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples
> ts-node node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine --config=./jasmine.json "/Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples/src/stackoverflow/69830430/index.test.ts"

Randomized with seed 02843
Started
.


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 0.014 seconds
Randomized with seed 02843 (jasmine --random=true --seed=02843)
```

The test reporter is generated in the `test-reporter` folder.

[image]

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jasmine-examples

Comment: I was able to get It working! Thanks very much for the detailed explanation, @slideshowp2! Very happy to have people like you here to help us :)